# How to set multiple timezones in Gnome Classic?

Tags: indicator, gnome-classic, timezone

For some strange reason, additional timezones cannot be added to the clock using the date-time indicator in Gnome Classic (Ubuntu 12.04). I used Unity before I switched to Gnome Classic, and it was possible to add more timezones. Even in Gnome Classic I can see the other timezones in the menu of the date-time indicator which I added when I was still using Unity. When I go to System Settings > Date and Time, there is no option for adding other timezones. How can I set additional timezones in Gnome Classic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**background**

The unity-indicator as you may have gathered does not have the same *capabilities* as Unity.  The developers have patched the gnome-libraries to give this integration.  However - by design - they have left the Gnome-Shell & Gnome-Classic desktops as vanilla as possible.  This is by expression wish by the gnome-developers.

Thus you will need a slightly more inventive solution - this answer will give you one such suggestion.

**use the clock applet**

[image]

Temporarily add the *clock* applet to the panel.

Find your location by clicking *edit* in the applet

Next look carefully at the locations:

[image]

The value you are interested in is *timezone city*

In this example:

```
America/Port_of_Spain Piarco
Europe/Rome Verona
```

Next fire up `dconf-editor`

#### [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools]

Look at the *locations* field as shown and add your new location(s) - each entry is in the format `,'timezone city'` i.e. separate entries with commas

[image]

You then will automatically update your date-time indicator.  You can finish off by deleting the clock applet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. As medigeek says in the other answer, the list of timezone strings is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones so you may not need the clock applet. Also, just an obvious note for anyone else doing this: after editing the Locations list, do tick "Show locations" as well!

Comment: This seems to be the only way to set multiple time locations in Ubuntu 15.04. The official GUI stops working for me after I add the first location (no drop down, a red circle with a white bar sign if I try to type it in). If anyone else is experiencing that, let me know, and I will file a bug on launchpad.

Answer (score 4):

If the "Choose locations" is missing from the Date and Time control but it does work, you should file a bug about it:

```
ubuntu-bug gnome-session-fallback
```

You can actually edit it manually through dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Select com > canonical > indicator > datetime

Look at the `locations` value.

```
['UTC UTC', 'Asia/Nicosia Nicosia']
```

Purely guessing, I think the first (e.g. *Asia/Nicosia*) is the time zone name and the second (e.g. *Nicosia*) is the name that appears in the indicator menu (tray icon).

You can find the list of time zones here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones