# How do I add missing cities for the other locations on the time & date clock?

Tags: time, clock, date

I want to add 'Amsterdam' and 'San Francisco' to my "Time in other locations" setting on the clock, but those cities seem to be missing. What is wrong? How do I add them?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some locations, you should to write all the name of the location so that this to appear. Happens to me as well if I do not write all the name. Also, an internet connection seems to be obvious in this case.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dconf-editor` to add cities.

```
com->canonical->indicator->datetime->locations
```

Edit locations:

```
locations = ['Europe/Moscow Moscow', 'America/Los_Angeles Santa Clara']
```

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155151/how-to-set-multiple-timezones-in-gnome-classic). Available timezones [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man3/DateTime::TimeZone::Catalog.3pm.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: In the current Ubuntu (17.10), this is the only acceptable answer. Everybody suggests installing an extra app that adds its own clock, but this is the only way of interacting with the default clock, which supports locations without extra tools.