# Editing time zones

Tags: time, date

I am using Ubuntu 20.4.5 and Gnome version 3.36.8.

In the top panel, I find the local date and time. When I left-click on that, there appears a calendar and, below that, my city's name and the local time, followed by the names of three other cities and their local times. I must have added those other cities at some point. I'd now like to change one of those additional cities, but I don't remember how I added the extra cities and now can't figure out how. Is there some configuration file that I can edit? I can't find a way to do what I want by using Date & Time in the system settings.

Thanks,

Leslie

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to reply, user68186. Unfortunately, it doesn't. It involves the installation of additional software. My existing cities and times are there with only the use of indicator applet complete. It's them I'm hoping to edit. I'm sure there must be a configuration file that contains the relevant information, but where to find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add missing cities for the other locations on the time & date clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301337/how-do-i-add-missing-cities-for-the-other-locations-on-the-time-date-clock)

Answer (score 0):

I found here the answer that worked for me: [How do I add missing cities for the other locations on the time & date clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301337/how-do-i-add-missing-cities-for-the-other-locations-on-the-time-date-clock)

By using the dconf-editor, I was able to amend my cities list as I wanted.